# How to find substring in string with wildcards

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I have a string like this (could be longer)

```
string list = "ABCDGGWWWW1234567 ABCDGGWWWW1234568 ABCDGGWWWW1234569 ";
```

Now I need to check if the substring `ABCDGGWWWW1234568` is in this string.
This I can do like the following

```
list.IndexOf("ABCDGGWWWW1234568 ") >= 0;
```

but, now I have the following problem,
if I would look for the substring `ABCDXXWWWW1234568` then this must also result in true

To explain the problem, when I search than the 5th and 6th character can also be XX
In other words,  `ABCDGGWWWW1234568` = `ABCDXXWWWW1234568`

It is always both characters that will be `XX` or the original value, not just one. Also the strings will always be 17 digits long. And they will always be uppercase.

So what would be the most efficient way to accomplish this ?

I was hoping that I could use wildcards like

```
list.IndexOf("ABCD__WWWW1234568 ") >= 0;
list.IndexOf("ABCD??WWWW1234568 ") >= 0;
```

but unfortunate that does not works, it never finds the index and always returns -1

**EDIT**
Thanks to @PanagiotisKanavos I have managed to get it working like this

```
chassis = chassis.Substring(0, 4) + @"\S{2}" + chassis.Substring(6, 11) + @"\s+";
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(list, chassis);
```

Comment: `IndexOf` doesn't have wildcards. You need regular expressions for this. Use the `Regex` class

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos would you happen to have some example for me ? I am new to regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IndexOf` doesn't have wildcards. You need [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0) for this. Use the [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0) class, for example:

```
var found=Regex.IsMatch(list,"ABCD\S{2}WWWW1234568\s+");
```

`.` matches any character. `\S` matches any non-whitespace character. `\S{2}` matches exactly two non-space characters. `\s+` matches one or more *whitespace* characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            if ("ABCDGGWWWW1234567 ABCDGGWWWW1234568 ABCDGGWWWW1234569".Contains("ABCDGGWWWW1234568") || "ABCDGGWWWW1234567 ABCDGGWWWW1234568 ABCDGGWWWW1234569".Contains("ABCDXXWWWW1234568"))
            {
                var result = true; 
            }
```

Comment: Though this will work, it won't be easy to implement because I have to do this in a loop and the value of the 17long variable can change off course.